# Pull requests to a different base fork from private repo?

Tags: github

Say we have three repos here:

x/a-repo, which is the original repo, and private.
me/a-repo, which is my repo, forked from x's. Also private.
y/a-repo, which x gave to y, and y published as a public repo.

I want to make pull requests to y/a-repo. Do I have to start over with a new repo forked from y/a-repo? If so, would I have to redo my commits from scratch, or is there some way of porting the commits over?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the *Fork&Pull* model you need to be forked from Y.

Comment: So I would have to redo my changes? If so, do you know if there is a way to port my commits over?

Comment: You don't need to redo but to move your changes. It's pretty easy to do either by doing a merge from your current branch to a new branch. Or alternatively you could generate a patch and apply (see here https://ariejan.net/2009/10/26/how-to-create-and-apply-a-patch-with-git/)